# Exploring TCP/IP Communications

Tags: ping, tcpip

According to the Lab, "The ping fails because the IP address assigned to the switch is not on the same subnet as the IP address assigned to the workstation. Even though they are on the same network segment, the IP addresses are not on the same subnet."

If that's the case why can I ping 8.8.8.8 (Google Server) from my PC? I know the Google server is not on my subnet.

Basically, why is the same process taking place, but with different results?

Comment: I think this needs some more context. Where did that original quote come from, and what happened before it?

Answer (score 1):

Before devices on two separate IP subnets can talk to each other via IP, an IP router (or chain of IP routers) must be set up to act as a path between those two subnets. This is true even if both subnets exist on the same link-layer network (e.g. the same Ethernet LAN segment). There are some potential exceptions to this rule if both subnets are on the same link-layer network, but it's still true as a general rule even when both subnets are on the same link-layer network.

Your computer can reach 8.8.8.8 because there are many IP routers between your subnet and its subnet and those routers act as the paths between those subnets.

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to comment. I really do appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

It is not at all the same process.

If you have let's say 192.168.1.10 /25 and 192.168.1.150 /25 and they are in separate  subnets but get out to the internet through a router and you did not configure/enabled inter-VLAN routing or the equivalent, both addresses will be able to ping something on the outside like 8.8.8.8 but they will not be able to ping each other.

Comment: Thanks I will try to go back and wrap my head around this some more.